# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iPhone Simulator start. App works on device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to test my app in the iPhone simulator so I click the "run" button. It shows the initial default splash screen but then it crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The error looks like it comes from some start-up routine.

The debugger points me to these two lines as the error:

```
0x8fe0f316  <+0276>  je     0x8fe0f342 <__dyld__ZN16ImageLoaderMachO12bindLocationERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextEmmPKS0_hPKclS7_+320>
0x8fe0f318  <+0278>  mov    %edx,(%edi)
```

The backtrace only shows the following functions being executed:

```
#0  0x8fe0f318 in __dyld__ZN16ImageLoaderMachO12bindLocationERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextEmmPKS0_hPKclS7_ ()
#1  0x8fe15ee3 in __dyld__ZN26ImageLoaderMachOCompressed6bindAtERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextEmhPKchliS5_PNS_10LastLookupE ()
#2  0x8fe218ff in __dyld__ZN26ImageLoaderMachOCompressed8eachBindERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextEMS_FmS3_mhPKchliS5_PNS_10LastLookupEE ()
#3  0x8fe22c42 in __dyld__ZN26ImageLoaderMachOCompressed6doBindERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextEb ()
#4  0x8fe0cc32 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader13recursiveBindERKNS_11LinkContextEb ()
#5  0x8fe0dea3 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader4linkERKNS_11LinkContextEbbRKNS_10RPathChainE ()
#6  0x8fe056af in __dyld__ZN4dyld4linkEP11ImageLoaderbRKNS0_10RPathChainE ()
#7  0x8fe0788d in __dyld__ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_ ()
#8  0x8fe018b1 in __dyld__ZN13dyldbootstrap5startEPK12macho_headeriPPKcl ()
#9  0x8fe01057 in __dyld__dyld_start ()
```

I've restarted Xcode, done a make clean, and more. The app starts fine on the device. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any static libraries that are perhaps not compiled for x86?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'm using standard frameworks and cocos2d. Not static libs as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` usually suggests that you're releasing something that's already released. You can find out more by adding the `NSZombieEnabled` flag to your environment.

Comment: Hmmm...MachOImageLoader tells me that the Library you're using hasn't been compiled for the architecture it should be run on. Double check its architecture!